# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from "xxx" : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've tried everything under the sun, configs disabling the SSL as some posts have suggested though I still get the same error. This is a PHP app running on windows2012 server through IIS on PHP 7.

Any idea what might be causing the error? I can access the WSDL through the webserver fine and all keys and urls are correct (I am primarily a .net dev and this PHP app has been handed to me to set up).

If you need anything else just holla.

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://developer.xxxx.com/API/1_0/SOAP/xxxxAPI.asmx?wsdl' : failed
>   to load external entity

```
if($xxxinitialised!==true){
        $soapurl = "https://xxxxxx/API/1_0/SOAP/xxxxxx.asmx?wsdl";

        $apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


        /* Initialize webservice using WSDL address */
        $ns = "https://developer.xxxx.com/API/1_0/SOAP/";

        $opts = array('ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false));

        $params = array ('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'verifypeer' => false, 'verifyhost' => false, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
                 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                 'location' => "https://developer.xxxxx.com/API/1_0/SOAP/xxxxAPI.asmx",
                 'uri' => $ns,'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, "connection_timeout" => 180, 
                 'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts));

        $client = new SoapClient($soapurl,$params);
```

Comment: Have you checked phpinfo(); output for the following support modules: Soap, xml (with libxml library installed), and openssl.  Soap won't work over https unless those three conditions are met.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem.  Soap, libxml and openssl are installed.  Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: same problem here, except i'm running on linux. openssl, soap, libxml are all installed